# How to add keys to array in CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating simple Profile page for users (users home page, not for other to see access). My controller:

```
<?php
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('Profile_model');
                $this->load->database();
                if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) 
                    redirect('auth/login');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

                $data = $this->Profile_model->getUserAccountInfoById($user_id);
                $data[] = $this->Profile_model->getUserProfileInfoById($user_id);

                $this->load->view('profile/profile', $data);
        }
}
```

My model:

```
<?php
class Profile_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();

        }

        public function getUserAccountInfoById($user_id)
        {
                $query = $this->db->get_where('user_accounts', array('id' => $user_id));
                return $query->row_array();
        }
        public function getUserProfileInfoById($user_id)
        {
                $query = $this->db->get_where('user_profiles', array('user_id' => $user_id));
                return $query->row_array();
        }
}
```

And view file:

```
<h2><?php echo $username; ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo $longitude; ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo $latitude; ?></h2>
```

The problem cames form fact that I have username inside user_accounts table but longitude/latitude inside user_profiles table. If I use model methods separately then everything work fine so inside the model everything is ok. But when I try to pass to my view data from both tables I get error :

```
Undefined variable: longitude
```

My question is about adding key/values to $data array. I have tried to google and from what I found I had to add [] but it still doesnt work (same error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `array_merge` to marge 2 arrays.you are creating a nested array.`var_dump($data)` will show you the content of array.

`$data` is a array.when you create `$data[]=...` , you are pushing another array to `data` array.so 2nd one is now a nested array.`longitude` is now not in the first level of array. it's on 2nd level(nested).

```
$data1 = $this->Profile_model->getUserAccountInfoById($user_id);
$data2 = $this->Profile_model->getUserProfileInfoById($user_id);
$data = array_merge($data1 , $data2 );
$this->load->view('profile/profile', $data);
```

or you can access nested array if you want.first print the content then it would be easy to decide how to access nested array

Comment: This works! I have additional question on the same topic. I did some experimenting and found that this work as well: In controller `$data['account_data'] = $this->Profile_model->getUserAccountInfoById($user_id);
    $data['profile_data'] = $this->Profile_model->getUserProfileInfoById($user_id); ` and view `<h2><?php echo $account_data['username']; ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo $profile_data['longitude']; ?></h2>`

Can you please explain me the difference so I could understand how to chose the best option?

Comment: @KārlisJanisels if you create `$data['account_data']` then you are crating nested array so you can access by `$data['profile_data'] `. array marge could conflict if you have same properties in both arrays in case you better use nested array.otherwise both should work.there is no need to nest a array if it's not necessary.`var_dump` is really helpful you can see the difference in array content when you use both ways.